# Google Cloud: how to copy files from VM Instance to computer desktop?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, download, google-cloud-storage, virtual-machine, gsutil

On SSH, I've tried using gsutil -m cp filename* Desktop to copy a file from the VM Instance to my computer desktop, like Google Cloud's own example in its documentation. I got a message saying that the file was copied successfully, but no mention of downloading anything, and I don't see the relevant file on my desktop. I've tried specifying the full desktop address instead of just 'Desktop', but SSH does not recognize the address.

Is there a way I can directly download files from the VM Instance to my desktop without having to go through a Google Cloud bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion this is the easiest [way](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#linux). Directly to local machine in a few steps.

[image]